# Why is OutputCache a result filter and not an action filter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The OutputCache attribute is commonly given as an example of a result filter in ASP.NET MVC. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28vs.98%29.aspx) is one place. As such it wraps execution of the ActionResult object. But isn't that object executed at the end of the action method? I'm confused as to how it allows a cached response to be used and prevents the action itself from executing if it only wraps execution of the ActionResult at the end of that method. I know that caching works, so there is clearly some obvious piece that I'm missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `OutputCacheAttribute` inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`, which in turn implements `IActionFilter`, and `IResultFilter`. Thus the `OutputCacheAttribute` is both an action filter and a result filter.

When  you think about it, this makes perfect sense. The logic behind a cache goes like this:

1. On execution

   - Is the item in the cache?
   - If Yes : **return from cache** (done)
   - If No, continue
2. Get result
3. On exiting

   - **put in cache**
   - return result

So part 1 is handled by the implementation of `IActionFilter`, if that doesn't immediately return a result, we continue with the action and the implementation of `IResultFilter` handles adding that result to the cache for future calls.

Thanks to ASP.NET being open source, this can be confirmed in code. Check out [`OutputCacheAttribute.cs` on codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs).

- Line 222 is where the cahce is checked during `OnActionExecuting` (part of `IActionFilter`)
- Line 237 - 249 the `OnActionExecuting` method sets up a callback that gets invoked during `OnResultExecuted` (part of `IResultFilter`)

Comment: Well, MVC is open source at least. But yeah, I should have looked there and confirmed my original intuition. So it really is both. Confusing that so many articles refer to it as a result filter.

Comment: Actually, I took a closer look at OutputCacheAttribute.cs and it doesn't look like any caching is happening inside OnResultExecuting and OnResultExecuted. All caching and retrieval happens inside OnActionExecuting. Seems like we should be calling it an action filter only.

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is a callback function that gets created during `OnActionExecuting`. This is what does the caching. BUT, it does not get invoked until `OnResultExecuted`. See the `CompleteChildAction` that is called during `OnResultExecuted`. So, if you were to not invoke the `IResultFilter` contract of `OutputCacheAttribute`, nothing would be cached.